# React: How does it know when a DOM compoent has been mounted, so that it can call componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

In general, i understand that it is difficult for us to know or get notified when a dynamic DOM element has loaded on screen, for e.g, there is no easy way to know whether or not a dynamic textbox is available in the DOM and focus on it, unless we do some kind of polling or do a setTimeout with 0 delay, so that it executes in the next tick when the DOM updation has already happened.

How does React know when the DOM has been updated, so that it can call lifecycle methods like componentDidMount or getSnapshotBeforeUpdate ? Does it use the setTimeout hack ?

EDIT: I understand the basics of the reconciliation algorithm, the linked doc in the comments does not talk bout how exactly react knows when the DOM element has been created/updated by the browser. I understand that the commit phase happens in 2 passes. In the first pass, all the Host(DOM) updates are done and in the second pass the relevant lifecycle methods are called (getSnapshotBeforeUpdated and componentDidMount), but since these 2 passes happen within the same [function](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/95a313ec0b957f71798a69d8e83408f40e76765b/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberScheduler.js#L523), how does React know that the DOM changes that have happened in the first pass, are available in the second pass ? Are these DOM updates synchronous ? If I access a DOM element left property in componentDidMount, would it be the new value after the updates are done to the DOM or the old value because when componentDidMount was called the browser might not have updated the DOM ?

Comment: Check this out: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

Comment: @HenryWoody thanks, i understand how reconciliation works, I am more interested in understanding if DOM updates are synchronous or React has some way to schedule the relevant lifecycle methods after the DOM has updated. Please see the edit

Answer (score 0):

To get a better understanding of how React lifecycle methods work, check [this cheatsheet](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/).

For your particular case, I would recommend to check the existence of the element (in this case textbox) in DOM. Example:

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (document.getElementById("ID-of-your-textbox")) {
    //anything that needs the textbox rendered
  }
}
```

But, if you end up with "my input is not yet rendered right after mount", you should try to put the check to `componentDidUpdate` method. Example:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (document.getElementById("ID-of-your-textbox")) {
    //anything that needs the textbox rendered
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a  scenario where "my input is not yet rendered right after mount" holds true ? why is that? wouldn't we expect the component to be available in the DOM after componentDidMount ?